# Calling a stored procedure with an out parameter

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-5

I'm trying to call a stored procedure that has one in parameter and two out parameters.

As a script, I call it like this:

```sql
set @MaxPrice = 0.00;
set @MinPrice = 0.00;
set @BSku = '1011001403';
call GetSkuMinMaxPrice(@Sku,@MaxPrice, @MinPrice);
```

and I get back my prices

Here's what I have for calling this with ef5:

```cs
decimal? minPrice;
decimal? maxPrice;

var skuParameter = new MySqlParameter("?SKU", productToUpload.Sku)
{
    Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
};
var maxPriceParameter = new MySqlParameter("?MaxPrice", SqlDbType.Decimal)
{
    Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
};
var minPriceParameter = new MySqlParameter("?MinPrice", SqlDbType.Decimal)
{
    Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
};
db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("call GetSkuMinMaxPrice(?SKU,?MaxPrice,?MinPrice)",
                               skuParameter, 
                               maxPriceParameter, 
                               minPriceParameter);

minPrice = minPriceParameter.Value as decimal?;
maxPrice = maxPriceParameter.Value as decimal?;
```

To me, this looks fine, but I get this error message from the MySQL server: `OUT or INOUT argument 2 for routine tng.GetSkuBaseMinMaxPrice is not a variable or NEW pseudo-variable in BEFORE trigger`.

So, what do I need to do to make this work, short of [not using Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10141637/asp-net-mvc-ef-calling-mysql-stored-procedure-with-out-parameters)?

Some of my research so far:

- [Syntax for everything except out parameters](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/522619/Implementing-CRUD-operations-in-MySQL-using-Entity)
- [Possible bug in MySQL](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=25970)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that this is a consequence of MySQL handling of out parameters. My workaround was to change the stored procedure to return a select query of the out parameters, create a POCO with public property names matching the stored procedure select result's column names.

**New stored Procedure call**

```
set @BSku = '1011001403';
call GetSkuPrices(@Sku);
```

**My POCO:**

```
private class PriceOutput
{
    public decimal? MaxPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal? MinPrice { get; set; }
}
```

**My calling code:**

```
decimal? minPrice = null;
decimal? maxPrice = null;

var skuParameter = new MySqlParameter("?SKU", productToUpload.Sku);
var basePrices = db.Database.SqlQuery<PriceOutput>("call GetSkuPrices(?SKU)",                                                       
                                                   skuParameter).FirstOrDefault();
if (basePrices != null)
{
    minPrice = basePrices.MinPrice;
    maxPrice = basePrices.MinPrice;
}
```

Comment: You sir, are a genius! I've been searching for the past hour for an answer to this and this is the solution.  I'm going to write up my answer now too!  Thank you for taking the time to answer your own question.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than attempting to use `OUT` parameters, I believe that these are not supported by MySQL for EF, return the values that you wanted to return from the `PROCEDURE` using a `SELECT` statement.

This is because each select statement that doesn't select `INTO` will be returned as a result set from the procedure.  [I found this out here.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8291/how-does-mysql-return-a-result-set-from-a-stored-procedure)

I wanted to return the number of affected rows from my stored proc, so I removed my out parameters and put this in it's place:

```
SELECT ROW_COUNT() AS Success;
```

I then created the following object to catch the value:

```
public class UsePasswordResult
{
    public int Success { get; set; }
}
```

Then I got the values using:

```
// Set values to desired parameter values
int quizId = 1;
string password = "mypassword";

UsePasswordResult result = this.Context.Database.SqlQuery<UsePasswordResult>("CALL UsePassword({0}, {1})", quizId, password).FirstOrDefault();
```

I hope that this helps someone!  I'm using EF6 and it works.